# How to pass array element to structure?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C. I have created this structure where I am trying to pass names from an existing array to one of the structure element  name[100], I am unable to understand how to pass it? Guys please help me and guide me how to do it. It would be a great help if somebody can guide me to a good structure tutorials(there are lots on web, but only basics)…thanks.

```
typedef struct new_st{

        char name[100];

        int icon_number;

        float calculation;

        }var;

char arr_name[] = {“name1”,  “name1”,  “name1”,  “name1” };/this lines throws error


int main(){

var *ptr_var;

New_var = malloc(sizeof(struct new_st)*100);

 strcpy(&arr_name[0], ptr_var[1].name);//this lines throws error

return 0;

}
```

Comment: New_var? you mean ptr_var? please give us clean code

Comment: it looks you have wrong quotation marks and an incomplete comment (one slash instead of two). Guess you should be more specific about '..its throwing so many errors..'.

Comment: @EmbeddedCrazy, still not declared, I think you mean `ptr_var = malloc(...)` I can edit it for you, if you want

Comment: What error? Also shouldn't the arguments be swapped around? It's `strcpy( destination, source)`

Answer (score 2):

use `strcpy()` :

`strcpy(New_var[0].name, arr_name[0]);`

Advice: do not cast the return value from `malloc()`

--EDIT after the source code posted --

You probably meant: `strcpy(ptr_var[1].name, arr_name[0]);` and

this is suppose to be:

```
char *arr_name[] = {“name1”,  “name1”,  “name1”,  “name1” };/*this lines throws error*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
var  *ptr_var;
ptr_var  = malloc(sizeof(struct new_st) * 100);

ptr_var[0].calculation = 1.5f; //assigning variable inside your struct 0 in your array of structs
ptr_var[0].name = "Foobar";


strcpy(&arr_name[0], ptr_var[1].name); //copy string 
//Free memory at end of your program
free(ptr_var);
```

Comment: `ptr_var[0]` would work only if `ptr_var` was defined as `var **ptr_var` - also thou shalt not cast malloc return

Comment: @Aniket it's a single dimensional array, AFAIK you can access them like an array?

Comment: Thanks to all...as you guy's suggested i have tried it...buti think something is going wrong ...its throwing so many errors...sorry friends!